# How can I configure my postfix server so reject_sender_login_mismatch doesn't block aliases of the main account?

Tags: smtp, postfix, authentication, saslauthd

I've recently setup postfix, dovecot, amavis and a suite of other tools using iRedMail, and I'm having difficultly authenticating to my outgoing mail server.

The issue is this:

xyz@mydomain.com is an alias to abc@mydomain.com.  I authenticate using abc@mydomain.com as that is the mailbox, but I'm actually sending from the alias.

Here's an example of the session:

```
EHLO mydomain.com
250-mx1.mymailserver.net
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 45728640
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
auth plain amlta0BhbHRlcm5hdGl2ZXJlYWxpdHkuY29tAGppbWtAY=
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
MAIL FROM: xyz@alternativereality.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: joe@gmail.com
553 5.7.1 <xyz@mydomain.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user abc@mydomain.com
QUIT
```

Here's the relevant section of postfix's main.cf:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated
```

Obviously the `reject_sender_login_mismatch` is the issue.  I would actually prefer to keep this functionality but support aliases.

*Can this be done, and/or is there a way to authenticate as the alias?*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for smtpd_sender_login_maps where you'll need to map the logins to aliases. See the [official doxumentation on smtpd_sender_login_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps).

Comment: Yes, thanks! I'm using a MySQL database for all those maps, so I had to change the default query from using mailbox to using alias table.  This appear to have worked so far.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

create a file called /etc/postfix/sender_login_maps

which contains mapped address

xyz@mydomain.com abc@mydomain.com

edit /etc/postfix/main.cf

add below line

smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_login_maps

run cmd postmap /etc/postfix/sender_login_maps

restart postfix services